# ImageOptimze - Will removing image Variant Ratio delete image files?

Tags: plugin-imageoptimize

We want to remove an image ratio from out variant options. Will the files with that image size automatically be removed when we do so? If not how do we ensure they are?

We are looking to remove them to increase the storage amount on our s3 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [Image Optimize](https://nystudio107.com/plugins/imageoptimize) just uses regular old Craft Transforms to do its thing. So whatever would happen to transformed images that you deleted the transform for would happen here as well.

I don't know the answer specifically, but if I had to guess, it'd be that Craft will not "clean up" its image transforms, and delete the ones that are no longer used. But you can do that manually, have it rebuild your Asset Indexes.